# How to prefer software installed in /usr/local

Tags: software-installation, libraries, graphics, mesa

I have installed `mesa` using apt in my system. This mesa is installed in `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf` directory. Now I compiled and installed the newest version of mesa manually from source, and it's installed in `/usr/local/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf`. But my system is still using mesa installed by the package manager.

How can I force system to use newer version of mesa compiled from source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play around with ld.so.conf(.d) and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable. You will find more on this topic in the ld.so(8) manual page.

```
If a shared object dependency does not contain a slash,
then it is searched for in the following order:

(...)

Using  the  environment  variable  LD_LIBRARY_PATH
(unless  the executable is being run in secure-execution
mode; see below).  in which case it is ignored.

(...)
```