# How to start TeamSpeak3 Client | Centos 7

Tags: centos, gnome, glibc, teamspeak

Im running a `centos-release-7-8.2003.0.el7.centos.x86_64` with a `GNOME 3.28.2`

I installed `TeamSpeak3-Client-linux_amd64-3.5.2.run` but when I try to start it I get the following error:

```
./ts3client_linux_amd64: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./libc++abi.so.1)
```

So apparently `GLIBC_2.18` is missing and Centos 7 only comes with `GLIBC_2.17`

**Is there some kind of workaround?**

*I tried building GLIBC_2.18 but it was not working properly and also very dangerous I was told.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not really dangerous, if you don't mess up with the installed glibc from the package manager. You don't need to touch it. For this purposes, there is a `/usr/local/` directory with `bin`, `lib`, (and so on...) directories inside, where you can place your manually compiled libraries (it's usually done by `make install` phase using makefile). Then you have to [preload these libraries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/578548/how-to-prefer-software-installed-in-usr-local) before you run TeamSpeak, to replace system default glibc with your compiled one.